# CPI and LPI value for FONT 14 in Cerner Command Language (CCL)

Tags: ccl

- What is the equivalent value for FONT 14 in Cerner Command
  Language's(CCL) character per inch (CPI) and Lines per inch (LPI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Def don't see a lot of CCL/Cerner Command Language questions on here.  From my experience, it usually looks like the below(not sure how to change font):

"{POS/463/254}{cpi/16}{b}", , "{endb}", ROW + 1

- POS-position on page
- cpi-characters per inch
- b-bold start
- endb-bold end
- ROW + 1-to next row, carriage return

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question but Font 14 is represented by AvantGarde Book-Oblique if available on the system.

For example, `{F/14}{LPI/6}{CPI/12}`

is AvantGarde Book-Oblique with six lines per inch and 12 characters per inch